# Convert an MS Word table to HTML

Tags: html, web

My emlpoyer has given me a heavily formatted table in an MS Word file with all kinds of colors, shapes and tons of content that I have to plug into a webpage.

I tried saving the Word file as HTML and then copying the code, but it is too bulky. Word to HTML tools didn't work neither.
Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Random thought, although I'm not sure - if there is any way to export the table into excel, and from there use a scripting language to read the excel file and certain properties of each cell and output HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it does need to be edited. And it is a long table, so a picture won't be a solution. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @michaelpri: You'll have to have many versions at different resolutions, text won't be selectable, the bandwidth requirements will skyrocket, etc.

Comment: @Linuxios It has too many colours and formatting, it is not a simple spreadsheet, so I am not sure the Excel would cut it

Comment: even not edited, just to copy parts, a picture is not a solution

Comment: @Newyork111: Excel is a *very* complex program, and I doubt that any colors and formatting you can do in word will trip it. What, specifically, are you worried about?

Comment: @ I am worried that I will loose the right formatting of the table. But hang on, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tool cleans up extra junk from Word generated html files, I've been using it for a while.

http://www.wordhtmlcleaner.co.uk/

Then you can use this tool to reformat you code so you can find the table your looking for easier:

http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Try [This tool](http://infohound.net/tidy/). With these options:

```
Doctype : auto

Drop empty paras

Logical emphasis

Output XHTML

Word 2000
```

That appears to keep the color and styling while cleaning it up.

Comment: This is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: @SunnyD  Thank you! I have just tried this option but unfortunately it has removed all the coloring which will take me forever to recreate by hand... Thank you for the suggestion though, those are nice tools for future use with less crazy tables:)

Comment: @Newyork111 hmmmm ok. Check my edit to see if that works. The new tool cleans it up but it keeps the color.